# Extract output from Powershell window to a string

Tags: c#, powershell

In my C# app, I have to run some PowerShell scripts. I copied paste from [this site](https://techhelpguy.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/run-powershell-script-in-a-process-and-monitor-it-c/) code about how to run the scripts.

My question: suppose I want to use the code from the link, how can I extract the PowerShell output to some string or to some `.txt` file?

EDIT:

If you want to test this code for answering this post, you need:

- add reference to `System.Management.Automation` dll
- add `requireAdministrator` inside `app.manifest`

Comment: Redirect it.. just like any other shell.  That's a pretty bad article as a side-note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C), you can extract the output with `Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();`, here a code example, note this would extract the PowerShell output to StringBuiler and would hide the PowerShell window:

```
 string RunScript(string pathToYourScript){
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

            using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("prog", this);

                using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(string.Format("$env:path = \"{0};\" + $env:path", pathToYourScript));

                    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(path);
                    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

                    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

                    }

                    var outDefault = new Command("out-default");
                    outDefault.MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
                    pipeline.Commands.Add(outDefault);

                    return stringBuilder;
                    }

                }
            }
```